# Within Team Explorer, is there a way to persist changes without merging them?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I work on a project that has a series of configuration files.  From time to time, these files need to be updated with new properties or settings, or we update how content is stored in some of these fields.  This means that we need to update these files to our project source control since we need to push these changes to all of the devs on this project, when these changes occur.

However, 95% of the time we want to ignore the changes in our local configs because they contain data-specific changes that are specific to a particular developer or his machine.

What I'd like to do within TFS is choose whether to commit the changes in these configuration files, or not, with each upload.  Preferably, I'd never commit my personal changes (as they relate to my personal, localized data.)  However, if I unstage this work, I can't switch branches until the changes are committed.  If I undo the work, it's quite a pain to switch branches and then manually recreate all of those personal changes.

Is there away in TFS to store a set of changes, and when I update or switch my local branch, re-apply the changes to my local working set? Also, I don't need TFS to ignore these file-changes.  Sometimes I do need to upload changes, especially when we're adding new config keys or changing the structure of the data.  In such a case, I push up my file and everyone else will see the change in structure.  However, if we can all apply localized patches to the specific regions/portions of the files with our user-specific code, it will save us a lot of time in re-integrating these files into our local, working projects. Can this be done?

Comment: Read about shelf sets.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could use **shelvesets** to handle the situation.

Since some of the pending changes that are not ready for check in, you could suspend your work and work on a different task/branch.

You can move your **pending changes** to a shelveset on the server and then clean your workspace. The shelveset saves and stores not only your file revisions, but also the **Comment**, the **list of Related Work Items**, and **check-in notes** (if you evaluate policies before shelving).

After the work have done, you could resume the shelveset to pending changes, unsheveset to local and keep working on it.

You could do this either from VS IDE or tf command line, more details please refer this tutorial: **[Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)**